# Xcode - Privacy - Camera Usage Description won't ask the permission for the camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, info.plist

My app developed in Xcode with Objective-C should ask for the camera permission in order to reply to a **SIP** video call.
Although i wrote the Privacy - Camera Usage Description Key into my info.plist file the app only asks for the microphone permission and **not for the camera permission** and when I start a video call it crash.

This is my info.plist file:
[My info.plist file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/br7Fj.png)

Also, If I go to app settings in iOS Settings there is no camera permission switch.

**Update with code as requested**

To make a video call i use the **ABTO VoIP SDK**.

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AbtoSipClientWrapper/AbtoSipPhoneObserver.h>
#import "Global.h"
#include "GenDefs.h"

#define kNotifKey                                    @"key"
#define kNotifKey_IncomingCall                        @"icall"
#define kNotifKey_IncomingMsg                        @"imsg"
#define kNotifCall_SessionId                        @"sid"
#define kNotifCall_RemoteInfo                       @"rinfo"
#define kNotifKey_IncomingIm                        @"iim"

@interface ImMessage : NSObject {
@public
    NSString *from;
    NSString *to;
    NSString *text;
    BOOL isRead;
}
@end

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, AbtoPhoneInterfaceObserver> {
@public
    UINavigationController *navController;
    UILocalNotification *lastCallNotification;

    BOOL checkIconLaunch;
    NSMutableArray *imMessages;
}

+ (AppDelegate *)sharedInstance;

@property (readwrite,nonatomic) AbtoPhoneInterface* phone;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILocalNotification *lastCallNotification;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL checkIconLaunch;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL connected;


- (void)addMessage:(ImMessage *)message;
- (NSMutableArray *)getIMs;
- (void)restoreIms;
- (void)storeIms;

@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate () {
}

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize phone;

+ (AppDelegate *)sharedInstance{
    return (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    phone = [AbtoPhoneInterface new];
    [phone initialize:self];
    return YES;
}


#pragma mark - UISceneSession lifecycle


- (UISceneConfiguration *)application:(UIApplication *)application configurationForConnectingSceneSession:(UISceneSession *)connectingSceneSession options:(UISceneConnectionOptions *)options {
    // Called when a new scene session is being created.
    // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
    return [[UISceneConfiguration alloc] initWithName:@"Default Configuration" sessionRole:connectingSceneSession.role];
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didDiscardSceneSessions:(NSSet<UISceneSession *> *)sceneSessions {
    // Called when the user discards a scene session.
    // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
    // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    [phone deinitialize];
}

#pragma mark Abto SIP SDK delegate

- (void)onRegistered:(NSInteger)accId {
    //[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_PHONE_EVENT object:@(PhoneEventsRegSuccess)];
}

- (void)onRegistrationFailed:(NSInteger)accId statusCode:(int)statusCode statusText:(NSString*)statusText {
  //  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_PHONE_EVENT object:@(PhoneEventsRegFailed)];
}

- (void)onUnRegistered:(NSInteger)accId {
  //  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_PHONE_EVENT object:@(PhoneEventsUnregSuccess)];
}

- (void)onRemoteAlerting:(NSInteger)accId statusCode:(int)statusCode {
   // [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_PHONE_EVENT object:@(PhoneEventsRemoteAlerting)];
}

- (void)onIncomingCall:(NSInteger)callId remoteContact:(NSString *)remoteContact {
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_CALL_EVENT object:@(CallEventsIncoming) userInfo:@{CALL_ID_ARGUMENT:@(callId), CONTACT_ARGUMENT:remoteContact}];
}

- (void)onCallConnected:(NSInteger)callId remoteContact:(NSString *)remoteContact {
  //  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_CALL_EVENT object:@(CallEventsConnected) userInfo:@{CALL_ID_ARGUMENT:@(callId)}];
}

- (void)onCallDisconnected:(NSInteger)callId remoteContact:(NSString *)remoteContact statusCode:(NSInteger)statusCode message:(NSString *)message {
  //  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_CALL_EVENT object:@(CallEventsDisconnected) userInfo:@{CALL_ID_ARGUMENT:@(callId), STATUS_ARGUMENT:@(statusCode)}];
}

- (void)onCallAlerting:(NSInteger)callId statusCode:(int)statusCode {
  //  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_CALL_EVENT object:@(CallEventsAlerting) userInfo:@{CALL_ID_ARGUMENT:@(callId), STATUS_ARGUMENT:@(statusCode)}];
}

- (void)onPresenceChanged:(NSString *)uri status:(PhoneBuddyStatus)status note:(NSString *)note {

}

- (void)onCallHeld:(NSInteger)callId state:(BOOL)state {

}

- (void)onToneReceived:(NSInteger)callId tone:(NSInteger)tone {

}

- (void)onTextMessageReceived:(NSString *)from to:(NSString *)to body:(NSString *)body {

}

- (void)onTextMessageStatus:(NSString *)address reason:(NSString *)reason status:(BOOL)status {

}

- (void)onTransferStatus:(NSInteger)callId statusCode:(int)statusCode message:(NSString *)message {
  //  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_CALL_EVENT object:@(CallEventsTransfering) userInfo:@{CALL_ID_ARGUMENT:@(callId), STATUS_ARGUMENT:@(statusCode), MESSAGE_ARGUMENT:message}];
}

- (void)onZrtpSas:(NSInteger)callId sas:(NSString *)sas {
  //  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_CALL_EVENT object:@(CallEventsZrtpSas) userInfo:@{CALL_ID_ARGUMENT:@(callId), MESSAGE_ARGUMENT:sas}];
}

- (void)onZrtpSecureState:(NSInteger)callId secured:(BOOL)secured {
    NSLog(@"ZRTP secured = %@", secured ? @"YES" : @"NO");
 //   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_CALL_EVENT object:@(CallEventsZrtpSecureState) userInfo:@{CALL_ID_ARGUMENT:@(callId), STATUS_ARGUMENT:@(secured)}];

}

- (void)onZrtpError:(NSInteger)callId error:(NSInteger)error subcode:(NSInteger)subcode {
    NSLog(@"ZRTP error = %ld(subcode = %ld)", (long)error, (long)subcode);
  //  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_CALL_EVENT object:@(CallEventsZrtpSecureState) userInfo:@{CALL_ID_ARGUMENT:@(callId), STATUS_ARGUMENT:@(error)}];
}

@end
```

**VideoCallViewController.h**
This is the "scene" presented when a SIP call is coming.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface VideoCallViewController : UIViewController {
    BOOL isRecording;
    BOOL enableSpeaker;
    BOOL isFrontCamera;
    BOOL isVideoMute;
    BOOL sendingVideo;

}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageViewRemoteVideo;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonPick;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonHangUp;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonHangUpLadge;

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *number;
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger callId;
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL incoming;

- (IBAction)onButtonClick:(UIButton *)sender;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

**VideoCallViewController.m**

```
#import "VideoCallViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVCaptureOutput.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVCaptureDevice.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVCaptureInput.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVMediaFormat.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

#define ACTION_SPEAKER_ON           @"Turn Speaker On"
#define ACTION_SPEAKER_OFF          @"Turn Speaker Off"
#define ACTION_OPEN_DTMF            @"Send DTMF"
#define ACTION_START_RECORDING      @"Start Recording"
#define ACTION_STOP_RECORDING       @"Stop Recording"
#define ACTION_SHOW_RTT             @"Show RTT"

#define kColorsDarkBlack [NSArray arrayWithObjects: \
(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:.1f green:.1f blue:.1f alpha:0.7] CGColor], \
(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.f green:0.f blue:0.f alpha:0.7] CGColor], \
nil]
#define kColorsBlue [NSArray arrayWithObjects: \
(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:.0f green:.0f blue:.5f alpha:0.7] CGColor], \
(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.f green:0.f blue:1.f alpha:0.7] CGColor], \
nil]
#define kColorsLightBlack [NSArray arrayWithObjects: \
(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:.2f green:.2f blue:.2f alpha:0.7] CGColor], \
(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:.1f green:.1f blue:.1f alpha:0.7] CGColor], \
(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.f green:0.f blue:0.f alpha:0.7] CGColor], \
nil]


@interface VideoCallViewController ()

@end

@implementation VideoCallViewController {
    NSInteger dtmfLen;
}

@synthesize imageViewRemoteVideo;
@synthesize buttonPick;
@synthesize buttonHangUp;
@synthesize buttonHangUpLadge;


- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        isRecording = NO;
        enableSpeaker = YES;
        dtmfLen = 0;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onPhoneNotification:) name:NOTIFICATION_PHONE_EVENT object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onCallNotification:) name:NOTIFICATION_CALL_EVENT object:nil];

    [UIDevice currentDevice].proximityMonitoringEnabled = YES;

    AbtoPhoneInterface* phone = [AppDelegate sharedInstance].phone;

    [phone setRemoteView:self.imageViewRemoteVideo];
//    [phone setLocalView:viewLocalVideo];

    if (self.incoming) {
     //   labelStatus.text = @"Incoming video call from";//NSLocalizedString(@"INVIDEOCALL_KEY", @"");

        buttonHangUp.hidden = NO;
        buttonPick.hidden = NO;
        buttonHangUpLadge.hidden = YES;

    } else {
        self.callId = [phone startCall:self.number withVideo:YES];
    //    labelStatus.text = @"Dialing";//NSLocalizedString(@"VIDEOCALL_KEY", @"");

      //  buttonPick.hidden = YES;
    //    buttonHangUp.hidden = YES;
        buttonHangUpLadge.hidden = NO;
    }

   /* labelRemoteParty.text = self.number;
    labelRemoteParty.hidden = NO;
    buttonActions.hidden = YES;
    stopVideoButton.hidden = YES;
    switchCameraButton.hidden = YES; */
 //   imageViewRemoteVideo.hidden = YES;
   // viewLocalVideo.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (self.callId == kInvalidCallId) {
        [self closeView];
    }
}



- (void)onCallNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
}

- (void)onPhoneNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
}

- (void)closeView {
   /* if (self == [ApplicationDelegate.navController topViewController])
        [ApplicationDelegate.navController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    DLog(@"closeView"); */
}


- (IBAction)onButtonClick:(UIButton *)sender {

    AbtoPhoneInterface* phone = [AppDelegate sharedInstance].phone;

    if(sender == buttonHangUp || sender== buttonHangUpLadge) {
        [phone hangUpCall:self.callId status:486]; /* TODO: 0 - use defalt status */
    } else if(sender == buttonPick) {
        [phone answerCall:self.callId status:200 withVideo:YES];
    }
}




@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController  {
    NSString* vcNumber;
    NSInteger vcCallId;
    BOOL vcIncoming;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AbtoPhoneConfig* config = [AppDelegate sharedInstance].phone.config;
 //  [config loadFromUserDefaults:SETTINGS_KEY];
     config.regUser = @"myUsernameHere";
     config.regPassword = @"myPassHere";
     config.regDomain = @"sip.antisip.com";
    [AppDelegate.sharedInstance.phone finalizeConfiguration];

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onCallNotification:) name:NOTIFICATION_CALL_EVENT object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onCallNotification:) name:NOTIFICATION_CALL_EVENT object:nil];
}


- (void)onCallNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSLog(@"Inizializzare CAll view");

    NSInteger status = [[notification object] integerValue];

       if (status == CallEventsIncoming) {
           NSInteger callId = [[notification.userInfo valueForKey:CALL_ID_ARGUMENT] integerValue];
           NSString *contact = [notification.userInfo valueForKey:CONTACT_ARGUMENT];

           if (callId != kInvalidCallId) {
               UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
               AppDelegate *appDelegate = [AppDelegate sharedInstance];
               NSString *remotePartyNumber = [AbtoPhoneInterface sipUriUsername:contact];
               UIApplicationState state = app.applicationState;

               [appDelegate.phone setSpeakerphoneOn:YES];
               if ((state == UIApplicationStateBackground) || (state == UIApplicationStateInactive)) {
                   UILocalNotification *localNotification = [UILocalNotification new];
                   if (localNotification) {
                       localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", remotePartyNumber, @"calling"];
                       //            localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
                       localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = ++app.applicationIconBadgeNumber;
                       localNotification.repeatInterval = 0;
                       NSDictionary *userInfo = @{ kNotifKey: kNotifKey_IncomingCall,
                                                   kNotifCall_SessionId : @(callId),
                                                   kNotifCall_RemoteInfo: contact };

                       localNotification.userInfo = userInfo;
                       [[UIApplication sharedApplication]  presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
                      // ApplicationDelegate.lastCallNotification = localNotification;
                   }

               } else {

                   vcNumber = remotePartyNumber;
                   vcCallId = callId;
                   vcIncoming = YES;
                  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue1" sender:self];
                 /*  VideoCallViewController *nextController = [appDelegate.phone isVideoCall:callId] ? [VideoCallViewController new] : [VideoCallViewController new];
                   nextController.number = remotePartyNumber;
                   nextController.callId = callId;
                   nextController.incoming = YES;
                   [appDelegate.navController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];  */
               }
           }
       } else if (status == CallEventsDisconnected) {
         //  ApplicationDelegate.lastCallNotification = nil;
       }
}

- (void)onPhoneNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segue1"]) {

        VideoCallViewController *nextController = [segue destinationViewController];

        nextController.number = vcNumber;
        nextController.callId = vcCallId;
        nextController.incoming = vcIncoming;
    }
}

@end
```

The call code is fine, because I tested it multiple times. The issue is that the app **does not ask for the camera permission**.

Comment: Read doc, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture_on_ios

Comment: Upload your code to get answer

Comment: **you** need to ask for permission, just setting this value in the plist doesnt do it for you.

Comment: Scriptable: I did a sample app with just the key and it asked the permission without writing any additional line of code. In this app, no.

Comment: @AlfredWoo I added my code as you requested.

Comment: add your console log when it crashes.

Comment: @Sagarkoyani I get a Bad Access. I tried to enable zombies objects but it does not help me